# ajax error: Uncaught ReferenceError: Ajax is not defined

Tags: ajax

```
<Script>
        new Ajax.Request('http://impact.brighterplanet.com/automobiles.json', {
                automobile_fuel:'diesel',
                daily_distance:'1389.45',
                size_class:'Midsize suv',
                timeframe:2013-01-01/F2014-01-01,
                KEY:'46feab14298d36f0d8b48304f81fe068',

                onSuccess: function(response) {
                    alert(response.decisions.carbon.object.value);
                }
        });

</script>
```

i have one error "Uncaught ReferenceError: Ajax is not defined "
what can i do................................

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you are using Prototype. Have you included the appropriate js files before this script tag?