# Uncaught ReferenceError: Ajax is not defined

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, mybb

I got an error in my mybb forum. I used a plugins for advance stats. But i got an error in console about "Uncaught ReferenceError: Ajax is not defined" So that's why my website not loading latest post from top.

Website: http://satfriends.net/index.php

Here is my code

```js
<!-- start: changuondyu_stats_script -->
 <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
  var fcmenu;
var listtab = new Array();
listtab[0] = "allforum";
listtab[1] = "inforum&listforumid=8";
listtab[2] = "inforum&listforumid=21,15,7";
listtab[3] = "inforum&listforumid=14";


function cswitch(taborder)
{
fcmenu = listtab[taborder];
document.getElementById('ct'+taborder).className = 'thead';
for (i = 0; i <= 3; i++)
{
 if (i != taborder)
   {
    document.getElementById('ct'+i).className = 'tcat';
   }
}
changstats_post();
}

function hshowpost(request)
{
  if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200)
 {
 document.getElementById('chang_latestposts').innerHTML = request.responseText;
 document.getElementById('cprogress_post').style.display="none";
 }
}
function hshowtop_user(request)
{
  if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200)
 {
 document.getElementById('chang_top_user').innerHTML = request.responseText;
 document.getElementById('cprogress_top').style.display="none";
 }
}
function hshowtop_forum(request)
{
  if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200)
 {
 document.getElementById('chang_top_forum').innerHTML = request.responseText;
 document.getElementById('cprogress_top').style.display="none";
 }
}


function changstats_post()
{
 document.getElementById('cprogress_post').style.display="inline";
 fcresult = document.getmenu.choosekq.value;
 new Ajax.Request('xmlhttp.php?do='+fcmenu+'&result='+fcresult, {method: 'GET', postBody: null, onComplete: function(request) { hshowpost(request); }});
}
function changstats_top_user()
{
 document.getElementById('cprogress_top').style.display="inline";
 fcmenu_top_user = document.getmenu.choosetop_user.value;
 fcresult = document.getmenu.choosekq.value;
 new Ajax.Request('xmlhttp.php?do='+fcmenu_top_user+'&result='+fcresult, {method: 'GET', postBody: null, onComplete: function(request) { hshowtop_user(request); }});
}
function changstats_top_forum()
{
 document.getElementById('cprogress_top').style.display="inline";
 fcmenu_top_forum = document.getmenu.choosetop_forum.value;
 fcresult = document.getmenu.choosekq.value;
 new Ajax.Request('xmlhttp.php?do='+fcmenu_top_forum+'&result='+fcresult, {method: 'GET', postBody: null, onComplete: function(request) { hshowtop_forum(request); }});
}

cswitch(0);
changstats_top_user();
changstats_top_forum();


</script>
<!-- end: changuondyu_stats_script -->
```

Give e a solution for that, how can i fix it.

Thanks

Comment: Well, it can't find the definition of the `Ajax` object. Are you sure the script where the object is supposedly defined is included in this page?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ajax error: Uncaught ReferenceError: Ajax is not defined](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16335285/ajax-error-uncaught-referenceerror-ajax-is-not-defined)

Answer (score 2):

You have to include the reference to the api where the method `Ajax.Request` is included. In your case it seems that is `Prototype` library.

Include the library at the top of your html page:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/prototype/1.7.3.0/prototype.js"></script>
```